# Bash - Continuous String Manipulation

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, string

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$(basename "$1")"
FILE="${FILE/%.jpeg/.jpg}"
```

Is there anyway to glue these two lines together into a one-liner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FILE=$(basename "${1/%.jpeg/.jpg}")` worked for me.

test:

```
bash-$ ./test.sh /tmp/foo.jpeg
foo.jpg
```

script contents:

```
bash-$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/bash

FILE=$(basename "${1/%.jpeg/.jpg}")

echo "$FILE"
```

Comment: Since the two lines are kinda interchangable, this solution is so far the neatest... If the lines aren't interchangable `sed` will be definitely needed I guess.

Answer (score 11):

You can't nest expansions in bash (nor in ksh, ash and other shells apart from zsh). This is only a cosmetic limitation, since as you illustrate you can assign an intermediate expression to a temporary variable. It is a little annoying for one-liners, but in scripts it's arguably better for readability.

You could avoid using the external utility `basename` and use a string manipulation construct instead:

```
FILE="${1##*/}"; FILE="${FILE/%.jpeg/.jpg}"
```

Here, it happens that you can rewrite your script to [put the command substitution on the outside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24194/bash-continuous-string-manipulation/24210#24210). That's not a general phenomenon, nor do you gain anything other than a certain one-liner feeling.

Zsh, for better or for worse, does let you nest expansions:

```
FILE=${$(basename $1)/%.jpeg/.jpg}    # using basename
FILE=${${1##*/}/%.jpeg/.jpg}          # using string rewriting
```

Or you could use zsh's built-in construct instead of `basename`:

```
FILE=${${1:t}/%.jpeg/.jpg}
```

Comment: good to know zsh support nest expansion

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for :

```
FILE=$(basename $1 .jpeg).jpg
```

The second parameter to basename is a suffix to be removed from the file name (see `man basename`)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a single `sed` command as in the following:

```
FILE=$(sed 's/.*\///;s/\.jpeg$/.jpg/' <<<"$1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Incorporating `sed`, this should do the trick:

```
FILE="$(basename "$1" | sed s/\.jpeg$/.jpg/)"
```

(This doesn't exactly answer your question because I can't; not sure if it's possible.)

Answer (score 1):

The Bash `${}` constructs work with *variable names*, so there's no way to embed a command directly. @sr_'s approach is an alternative if you don't mind the extra fork.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
FILE=$(basename "${1/%.jpeg/.jpg}")
```

can be shortened and made more portable with

```
FILE=$(basename "${1%.jpeg}.jpg")
```