# bash: one parameter substitution: beginning and end of string

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

*This question is not about how to accomplish  this with `sed`, `grep` or similar tools. **Please don't answer with those**.*

---

I have a string (it can be any string along the same structure `foofoo_barbar`, etc):

```
.foo_bar.kate-swp
```

and I just one to retrieve `foo_bar`, so remove the `.` at the beginning and `.kate-swp` at the end. I know I can use intermediate varibles like this:

```bsh
foo=".foo_bar.kate-swp"
foo="${foo#.}"
foo="${foo%.*}"
echo "$foo"
foo_bar
```

But I'm wondering if it can be done in just *one* substitution. I'm trying (and I mean a lot) along these lines:

```bsh
echo "${foo/!(*[a-z]).kate-swp/}"
.foo_bar
```

But

```bsh
# just an example of my failures
echo "${foo/.!(*[a-z]).kate-swp/}"
.foo_bar.kate-swp
```

Maybe this is not at all possible, but if it is, I'm always keen to learn.

Comment: What do you mean retrieve you have a string and you just want to pull one section of that string out?  Or are you trying to add to a string?

Comment: @JasonCroyle The question is good and clear: To remove a substring from the start and another from the end of the string. The general answer is [no, not without ugly workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/917260).

Comment: @Theophrastus Thanks, I should clarify in the question that the string is variable, but in similar structure.

Comment: @Theophrastus I can indeed, and as show in the question I can use intermediate variables. It's not about that *I don't want*, it's if *it's possible*. If it were I would be learning something new.

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks, "nested" is not a term I thought to make my searches. If you would want/like/can make an answer, you are welcomed.

Comment: In this question here, would be the perfect title line for this question, but alas, it's used there, so can't be used in any other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241266/nested-parameter-expansion

Comment: [Use parameter expansion to modify output of another expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253606/use-parameter-expansion-to-modify-output-of-another-expansion), [Bash - Continuous String Manipulation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24229/170373)

Comment: Note that you _can_ nest on the right-hand side of the expansion: [What is the right way to quote nested parameter expansions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556616/what-is-the-right-way-to-quote-nested-parameter-expansions)

Comment: @JasonCroyle I edited the question, do you consider it is clearer now?

Answer (score 4):

Some workarounds in Bash:

Regex match with capture:

```
$ foo='.foo_bar.kate-swp'
$ [[ $foo =~ ^[.]([^.]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
foo_bar
```

Split the string to parts on the dots:

```
$ foo='.foo_bar.kate-swp'
$ IFS=. read -r x var y <<< "$foo"; echo "$var"
foo_bar
```

But really, no, you can't nest expansions in Bash in the useful way. And the `${var/pattern/replace}` doesn't really work because the *pattern* needs to match a continuous part of the string, and there are no regex-style capture groups (i.e. no `s/xxx(main)yyy/\1/`).

You could nest the expansions in Zsh, though:

```
zsh% foo='.foo_bar.kate-swp'
zsh% echo ${${foo#.}%%.*}'
foo_bar
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question clarifying that the string coud be variable though with the same structure: `echo "${foo:1:7}"` would just work for that specific string.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, I know, that one is a joke ;) (I had it marked as such, but seem to have dropped it in an edit.) The others aren't really as brief as the nested expansion either.

Comment: Joke all around, I miss that in this site :) good humour is always refreshing.