# Pattern match both suffix and prefix in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, posix

I have this variable, and I want to remove both prefix and suffix:

```bsh
var="abcde"
echo "${${var#a}%e}"
```

I tried this snippet in zsh, and it works properly - returns `bcd`. It uses pattern matching (prefix and suffix).
Although, when I run it in posix compliant shell script (the reason I'm using pattern matching instead of bash string manipulation), I get output `bad substitution`.

What is the matter? Must I make another variable to store `"${var#a}"` into or can I do it in one line? I want posix compliant script.

Comment: This dont work on `bash` , maybe in `zsh`

Comment: @YetAnotherUser my bad, I meant `zsh`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637445/bash-one-parameter-substitution-beginning-and-end-of-string maybe this can help

Comment: @YetAnotherUser it's `bash` and `zsh`, I want it in pure shell script.

Comment: Yes, you must use an intermediary variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to have another variable, and yes, you can do it in a single line.

This is probably the most portable solution but it will overwrite the variable value (still using a single variable as mentioned in the question). It uses only parameter expansion of the shell language:

```bsh
var="abcde"
var="${var#a}" # remove prefix
echo "${var%e}" # remove suffix
```

One-liner may be always created as shown:

```bsh
var="abcde"; var="${var#a}"; echo "${var%e}"
```

If you do not want to overwrite the variable, function arguments are perfect temporary variables. Although your example is trivial, you may create a function for it, which hides the extra variable used. This approach is especially useful since there are no local variables in the POSIX shell:

```bsh
# this function runs in a subshell, so all new variables are lost on the return
remove_pre_post() (
    local_var="${1#a}" # uses the first argument
    echo "${local_var%e}"
)

var="abcde"
remove_pre_post "$var" # call function
```

Another POSIX-compliant solution may involve `sed`:

```bsh
var="abcde"
echo "$var" | sed 's/^a//; s/e$//'
```

You provided only the example without any pattern matching. Keep in mind that once pattern matching is a thing, you may see one solution better than the other depending on the pattern complexity.